# One to Many with Mongoose and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to create a one-to-many relationship with Category and Product.
I only have the _category_id on product model.
How I can see all products for a specific category?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
   name: {
     type: String,
     default: '',
     trim: true
   },
   _category: {
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
     ref: 'Category'
   }
});

mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
}
});
    CategorySchema.statics = {
  load: function(id, cb) {
    this.findOne({ _id: id  }).exec(cb);
  }
    };

    mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

I think I need to add the products variable or something like that on load method.
How I can do that?

Comment: You should declare your models to a variable `var category=mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);` so you can easily access them. You can then export and require your models if you want to store them in a separate files.

You're going about mongoDB all wrong. In your schema you're declaring types, because mongodb serializes to BSON(binary JSON). You cannot declare a function as a `type`. You can set a function for the `defaults` option. However, be aware this is not asynchronous. There's probably a better way to set an initial value, but that's out of context of mongoose.